# Determine the omega limit set for every point in $\Re^3$ for this dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, dynamical-systems, self-learning

The dynamical system is as follows

$$\dot x = -y \\ \dot y = x \\ \dot z = -x^2-y^2$$

Now by looking at the two dimensional system with only $x$ and $y$ I know that every point here is just a spiral. (centre manifold) http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%5B%7B-y%2C+x%7D%5D

So when adding in the $z$ part to make it 3 dimensional I will get like a spiral orthogonal to every point on the spiral in the two dimensional plane. (I hope I am making sense here).

I am struggling to fully visualise how it would look but what I think is that the omega limit points will be the circle around each point in the two dimensional plane.

But I don't know how to explicitly say what the omega limit set for each point is.

**Edit**: I will attempt to make myself more clear here.

But the stationary points of the DS can be found at $(x^*, x^*, z^*) = (0,0,z)$ which is basically the $z$ axis.

Also I know that for each point in the $x,y$ plane that their is a helix in the $z$ direction.

So now what I am thinking is that as time progresses each point will be moving towards the stationary point. Hence the z axis is the omega limit set?

Comment: Not spirals: solutions of $\dot{x} = y, \; \dot{y}  = -x$ are closed trajectories that lie on concentric circles $x^2 + y^2 = \textrm{const}$. You can actually check that for a full three-dimensional system also holds $x^2(t) + y^2(t) = \textrm{const}$.

Comment: Ok I see. I get that. But I cant seem to translate this to what the omega limit set should be

Answer (score 2):

You can be more specific (and use better terminology) than "spiral". The trajectories of the two dimensional system are circles centered on the origin, *except* that the origin is a stationary point. And the trajectories of the three dimensional system are helixes lying over those circles, travelling at a constant downward speed on each such helix, *except* that every point on the $z$-axis itself is a stationary point.

So, now ask yourself: As you travel at constant downward speed along a helix, what's the omega limit set, i.e. what points do you accumulate on? And as you sit unmoving on a stationary point, what's the omega limit set, i.e. what points do you accumulate on?

**Added:** Here's one way to pose the question to yourself regarding the omega limit set of a trajectory.

Imagine that you are an ant walking on one of these helix trajectories. You start walking downward, descending lower and lower and lower, as your $z$-coordinate decreases at a constant rate. Down, down, down, lower, lower, lower down the helix. You walk past some point $P$ (wave at it!), and continue on downward, lower, lower, lower, never returning anywhere near $P$ again (goodbye $P$!). **Are you accumulating on $P$?** Is $P$ in the omega limit set? If you are accumulating on $P$ then yes, $P$ is in the omega limit set. If you are not accumulating on $P$ then no, $P$ is not in the omega limit set.

Comment: See I am just getting confused trying to picture it in my head. I am not trying to purposely be unclear. I am just getting myself in a mess thinking about this. So yes, I do understand that in 2 dimensions they are circles centred at the fixed point. And that the added 3rd dimension is a helix. That's what I poorly tried to explain in the question. So what I should say is that the z axis is the omega limit set as they are the stationary points. So every point will move to there?

Comment: It may  help to get into the details. You ask if every trajectory (not 'point') will move to the z-axis. If that were true, then the value $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ would go to zero along every trajectory. But it doesn't; can you prove why?

Comment: @dbx Im so confused right now. I don't havea  clue

Comment: So, when not on z axis, the omega limit set are the points on the helix. When on z axis the omega limit set is the z axis?

Comment: I added a further discussion regarding the limit set.

Comment: @LeeMosher I know what an omega limit set is. I know the theory behind it. The problem I am having is that I CAN'T visualise the problem. Like I get it in 2-D but I actually don't know what it looks like in 3-D. That's why I can't understand what the omega limit set it

Comment: Okay, great, because for this problem you need no theory and only a straight-up application of the definition of the omega limit set of a trajectory. The helical trajectories have the form $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ where $z(t) \to -\infty$ as $t \to +\infty$ (because $\dot z$ is a negative constant on each trajectory). So, pick any point $P = (a,b,c)  \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Can you evaluate the limit as $t \to +\infty$ of the distance from $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ to $P = (a,b,c)$? And can you use that to determine whether or not $P$ is in the omega limit set of the trajectory $\gamma$?

Comment: @LeeMosher See the thing is. I know what the answer is. And it was what I actually thought of early. But I just kept confusing myself. If the point is not on $(0,0,z)$ then the omega limit set is empty. If it is on that line the the omega limit set is simply that point

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Comment: It might be worth spelling out one of the various definitions of the omega limit set, the one which I find easiest to apply (at least for this problem). For any trajectory $\gamma(t)$, its omega limit set is all limits of convergent sequences of the form $\gamma(t_n)$ where $t_n$ is a sequence of real numbers diverging to $+\infty$. So if $\gamma(t)$ is stationary, that point is the only point in the omega limit set. And if every sequence $\gamma(t_n)$ is divergent, then the omega limit set is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the limit set is but you can simplify this ODE by the following steps.

Note that the first two equations are uncoupled from the last one. Hence, divide both equations to obtain

$$dx/dy = -y/x \implies xdx = -ydy \implies x^2+y^2=c.$$

For certain intitial conditions $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ we have $c = x^2_0+y^2_0$.

Now, use $x^2+y^2=c$ to substitute $-y^2=x^2-c$ to obtain the last ODE as

$$dz/dt=-x^2+x^2-c=-c \implies z(t)=-ct+c_2=-(x_0^2+y_0^2)t+c_2.$$

Again we can use the initial conditions to determine $c_2=z_0$. Hence,

$$z(t)=-(x_0^2+y_0^2)t+z_0$$.
Can you complete it from here?